# How to put add-ons on Minecraft for Nintendo Switch?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, nintendo-switch

How can I add an add-on, or hack my Minecraft on Nintendo Switch lite?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How can I mod Minecraft on the Switch Lite? That doesn't seem unclear to me.

Comment: Step 1: https://switch.homebrew.guide/ or (I forgot where the other guide is) | Step 2: ??? (Don't have MC on the Switch)

Answer (score 0):

Mods on console have a pretty easy answer to that question.

1- If they give you the option, like with Skyrim, you can access a checked number of plugins. Pretty sure Skyrim is the only one with that tho.

2- You can't with a normal console. A homebrewed one maybe, but that is outside the scope of this site. (Homebrews jump into piracy real quick)

The thing is, for most mods, what you need to do is modify or add game files. 2 things that on consoles, where you can't access individual files, cannot do.

Comment: Bedrock edition does have some amount of mod support from mojang, so there is a easy way to add mods, the main thing is there arent many bedrock mods in general.  I dont own bedrock edition so I cant really test how to do it tho.

Comment: I'm always very confused as to what is what in minecraft editions but that means its option 1. You have a few approved mods that you can activate, but if its not on the lisst, no dice. And really, it would be pretty surprising it works the other way. Couldnt believe console manifacturers would love to let a game run any code on their machine, most of it not being approved.

Comment: "Pretty sure Skyrim is the only one with that" If I recall correctly Fallout 4 gives an option to use mod(s), I don't own ps4 version of it so I don't know for sure though.

Comment: Never played both of them so I'm talking on reputation here; but I would guess Fallout runs like skyrim: A shortlist of mods that have been vetted by Bethesda and probably whatever console company you are playing on.

Comment: Good answer, I actually didn't know homebrewing was illegal.

Comment: Dont think it is overtly illegal to homebrew (The local police wont come knock at your door only because you homebrewed your switch), but it is breaking the console TOS and that is a rule we have, if it breaks TOS its outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use addons on Nintendo switch but you will need realms. There is a video from dakonblackrose it might help you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I cannot see how this is supposed to help anyone. You didn't link to the video so we are clueless as to which one it is.